# How to get 'Products' on home page?

Tags: custom-post-types, themes, plugins, homepage

I am using query post in loop.php

```
query_posts( array('post_type'=>array('product','post'),'paged'=>$paged ) );
```

So that the custom post 'product' (woocommerce product) can be displayed on home page.

I am able to see 'product' & 'post' in home page of theme1 but not in theme2, what might be the problem?, suggest me place where I should check; What should I check?

Answer (score -1):

Here's a product loop I found:

```
    <ul class="products">
     <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 12
        );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile;
    } else {
        echo __( 'No products found' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
     ?>
    </ul><!--/.products-->
```

Maybe that will help.